# Is a pre-doctoral licentiate degree worth anything?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, job-search, degree

There exists a degree title called the [*licentiate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licentiate_(degree)#Finland_and_Sweden) in Finland and Sweden which is a graduate title beneath a full PhD title; I've heard it called, among other things, a "half PhD", a "PhD lite" or a "PhD for those already working". However, what formal or practical benefits can/does such a title actually confer, especially since being awarded a licentiate degree entails having a postgraduate degree anyway (a Master's degree, which very much could have entailed doing research itself)?

- Can the formal qualification and/or work done for it contribute towards a proper PhD at another institution, either immediately after or after some interim period?
- Is it accepted as proof of any kind of practical research experience in larger institutions outside of Finland and Sweden? From what I've gathered, it seems that research-oriented jobs are very strictly categorized as either "jobs for people with PhDs" or "jobs for everyone else", which suggests that a "not-quite-PhD" degree wouldn't actually open any doors and maybe even close some (due to e.g. being perceived as overqualified, as having "quit" a PhD program or as being "not able" to secure a proper PhD candidate position).

Answer (score 6):

Here is some experience from Sweden:

First of all, the licentiate isn't really a degree that you can study towards per se, at least not in our institution. Much more, it is an optional, but highly recommended, midterm step in doing a PhD. I guess there has to be some theoretical way of formally studying only towards a licentiate, but I do not know any such case and I would not really see a reason why you would want to do it.

> Is it accepted as proof of any kind of practical research experience in larger institutions outside of Finland and Sweden?

Presumably not. Even in Sweden the concept isn't well-known at all outside of academic circles. In practice there are more advantages to having a licentiate within academia than outside - for instance, post-lic PhD students in my department get a little higher salary and some small additional rights, such as being able to act as official primary supervisors for master students. However, mainly the licentiate is considered to be a semi-formal "half-time" exam for the PhD, and used as a test drive for the actual thesis defense.

One small additional thing:

> being awarded a licentiate degree entails having a postgraduate degree anyway (a Master's degree, which very much could have entailed doing research itself)?

In Sweden, and more generally in most of Europe, a master's degree isn't generally considered a "postgraduate" degree in the same sense as it is in the US. Our master programmes are primarily by-coursework with a one-semester thesis project at the end, and while the master programme should get students in touch with research, I don't think most people would consider the average master graduate to be a researcher in any definition of the word. Also, many (most?) of our bachelor graduates continue on into one of our master programmes. This is very different to the licentiate / PhD track, that only a small minority of students chooses.